# Sorting files in an array by the ocurrences of a word in it, php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, repeat

I'm making a search bar that searches files in a directory that have the word searched, then I want it to be added to an array by order of which one has more times the word asked to the one with less.
I'm working on PHP this is my code:

```
<?php
    
    if(isset($_POST['busqueda'])){
        $variable = utf8_encode($_POST['busqueda']);
    }
    $Array1 = array();

    foreach(glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
        $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
        if (strpos($contents, $variable)){
             $Array1[] = $filename;
      }
    }
```

I don't know how to do it exactly, I think that I should use `substr_count(file_get_contents($Array1[$position1]))` or something like that but I'm unsure how to make the sorting system, can someone help me!

```
print_r($Array1);

for($var1=0; $var1<sizeof($Array1); $var1++){
       echo "times on the file: ".$Array1[$var1]."<br>";
        echo substr_count(file_get_contents($Array1[$var1]));
  }
?>
```

Comment: If you can run bash commands through exec or similar function, you could use `tr ' ' '\n' < THEFILEPATH | grep THEWORD | wc -l` for a quick count of all of the occurances of THEWORD that happen to be in THEFILEPATH file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the substr_count itself. Then you need to use arsort to sort the array.

```
$Array1 = array();
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    if ( ($count = substr_count($contents, $variable)) ) {
        $Array1[$filename] = $count;
    }
}

arsort($Array1) ;

print_r($Array1);

foreach ($Array1 as $file => $count) {
    echo "times on the file($file): $count <br>";
}
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => 59 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 [4] => 50 [5] => 6 ) times on the file(0): 59 
times on the file(1): 50 
times on the file(2): 50 
times on the file(3): 50 
times on the file(4): 50 
times on the file(5): 6 

it doesnt save the $filename on the array :( 

(in the foreach i tried to open the $file with a fopen, so i can read line by line to display some content but it says that no file named 0,1,2,...)

Comment: Are u used rsort or arsort?

Comment: forgoit was a miss tyiping

Comment: its there an easy way to apply filtering? i mean to only show the elements that have more than x ammount of words when clicked a checkbox (or button)?

Answer (score 0):

Bash (available on at least Linux and Mac operating systems) makes it extremely easy to accomplish your task, because you can call commands through PHP's exec function, assuming it is not disabled by an administrator. If you're on Windows, then this will probably not work, but most people are using Linux for a production environment, so I thought this answer would be worthy of posting.

The following function is taken from CodeIgniter's file helper and only serves to fetch an array of filenames from a specified directory. If you don't need a function like this because you are getting your filenames from somewhere else, just note that this function can include the full file path for each file, and that's why I used it.

```
function get_filenames($source_dir, $include_path = FALSE, $_recursion = FALSE)
{
    static $_filedata = array();

    if ($fp = @opendir($source_dir))
    {
        // reset the array and make sure $source_dir has a trailing slash on the initial call
        if ($_recursion === FALSE)
        {
            $_filedata = array();
            $source_dir = rtrim(realpath($source_dir), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }

        while (FALSE !== ($file = readdir($fp)))
        {
            if (@is_dir($source_dir.$file) && strncmp($file, '.', 1) !== 0)
            {
                get_filenames($source_dir.$file.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $include_path, TRUE);
            }
            elseif (strncmp($file, '.', 1) !== 0)
            {
                $_filedata[] = ($include_path == TRUE) ? $source_dir.$file : $file;
            }
        }
        return $_filedata;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Now that I can fetch an array of filenames easily, I'd do this:

```
/**
 * Here you can see that I am searching 
 * all of the files in the script-library 
 * directory for the word "the"
 */
$searchWord = 'the';
$directory = '/var/www/htdocs/script-library';

$filenames = get_filenames(
    $directory,
    TRUE    
);

foreach( $filenames as $file )
{
    $counts[$file] = exec("tr ' ' '\n' < " . $file . " | grep " . $searchWord . " | wc -l");
}

arsort( $counts );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $counts );
echo '</pre>';
```

For a good explaination of how that works, see this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-text-file-with-the-comma

I tested this code locally and it works great.